# java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1009)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, nullpointerexception

```
       java.lang.NullPointerException
       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1009)
       at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:439)
       at ConvertReadings.Convertd(ConvertReadings.java:39)
       at UDPServer.main(UDPServer.java:73)
```

hibernate cfg file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
             <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:1111/DB</property>
        <property name="connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.autoReconnect"> true</property>
            <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
        <!--  <property name="c3p0.validate">true</property> -->
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property> 
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
```

ConvertReadings code is

```
public class ConvertReadings {
public String Convertd(String a, String b, String c1, String c0 ) throws Exception
{
    Converter con= new Converter();
    int x;
    double i = Float.parseFloat(a);
    if (b.equalsIgnoreCase("HUM"))
    {
        double c=Float.parseFloat(c1);
        double d=Float.parseFloat(c0);
        x=con.convert(c, d, i);
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }
    else if (b.equalsIgnoreCase("CO"))
    {
        double c=Float.parseFloat(c1);;
        double d=Float.parseFloat(c0);
        x=con.convert(c, d, i);
        return String.valueOf(x);
}
    return "Invalid sensor reading";
}
}
```

code where i am getting exception is

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
public class FetchCoeff {
public SessionFactory factory;
public String[] testing(String x, String y) { ///here x=DevID and y= sensor type
//Session session= null ;
String c[] = new String[30];
Session session = factory.openSession(); 
    try{
String q= "SELECT d.c1, d.c0, d.DevID, d.SensorType FROM SensorReadings d WHERE d.DevID= :DevID AND d.SensorType= :SensorType";
Query query = session.createQuery(q);
query.setParameter("DevID",x);
query.setParameter("SensorType", y);
System.out.println("query executed");
for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();){
      Object[] ob = (Object[]) it.next();       // I am Facing problem here
        c[1]= (String)ob[0];  // contains coeff 1 c1
        c[0]= (String)ob[1];  // contains coeff 0 c0    
     }
}catch(HibernateException e){
    System.out.println("Hibernate exception occured");
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception d){
    System.out.println("exception occured");
    d.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
session.close();
}
return c;
}
}
```

I had posted it few weeks before and i got solution for this from "JB Nizet" but it solved only one part now i am facing Null pointer exception in below part

```
                for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();){
             Object[] ob = (Object[]) it.next();
                c[1]= (String)ob[0];
                c[0]= (String)ob[1];
```

I think this object is throwing null pointer exception but i don't know how solve it. can anyone help me in this.. here i am created query and iterated result set and passing it to the string array.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct connect string `jdbc:mysql://localhost:1111/DB`? MySQL uses port 3306 as default. And your user is called `username` and has `password` as the password?

Comment: <property name="connection.url">
  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/praxeye1</property>
  <property name="connection.username">enviromote</property>
  <property name="connection.password">enviromote123</property>  ---- this is proper one... sorry

Comment: Why are you using a transaction, you are only reading not writing, so there is no need for a transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You're executing the above methods several times, and after some invocations, it throws the above exception.

The problem probably comes from the fact that you're reading the Hibernate configurationand creating a whole new session factory, with a new connection pool, at each method invocation.

The following should be done once and only once. The same session factory should then be reused at each method invocation:

```
Configuration cfg= new Configuration();
cfg.configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sessionfactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: ya exactly :) i did as u told and problem solved thank u very much sir for ur time and help :)

Comment: I got one more problem... please anyone help me,