# Do I use the correct JPA annotations for persisting my entities in my H2 database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

my problem:

```
@Entity
public class Container {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Element> containedElements;

    public final List<Element> getContainedElements() {
        return containedElements;
    }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Element {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Container myContainer;

    public final Container getMyContainer() {
        return myContainer;
    }

    public abstract Object getValue();

    public abstract void setValue(final Object newValue);
}

@Entity
public class StringElement extends Element {
    private String someValue;

    public final Object getValue() {
        return someValue;
    }

    public final void setValue(final Object newValue) {
        someValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

I have a container class containing probably many objects of an abstract class Element.
I have more than one implementation of this Element class, one of them StringElement.

Using the JPA API (provided by Hibernate) and a local H2 database and a small test class, I can persist entities of these classes and query the database for them and output them to the console.

Using Wildfly 8.0 (JBoss), the JPA API (provided by Hibernate) and a Wildfly-"managed" H2 database, I can persist entities, but when I query the database for a Container object, I cannot access the contained elements. Trying to do this results in the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1011)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:846)
```

I can query the database for a list of all StringElements in the database and parse the results. I can access the Container via getMyContainer(). Then when I try to access an Element via getContainedElements().get(0), I get the above error again.

Did I use the correct JPA annotations? How can I have a list of abstract objects in my container?

Comment: Is this issues a duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186755/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-sun-misc-floatingdecimal-readjavaformatstring)?

Answer (score 0):

@OneToMany annotation has FetchType.LAZY as default.
It looks like you are trying access containedElements when the Container entity is no longer managed by the persistence context.
You must read containedElements when the Container is managed by persistence context (if you want to leave FetchType.LAZY) or just change fetch to FetchType.EAGER:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
private List<Element> containedElements;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can finally answer this on my own:

The problem lies with multiple classes that inherit Element. Or rather, the cause of the error are two or more classes inheriting from Element which each have an attribute named **someValue**. The problem is that each attribute has a different primitive type.

Doing a select over all Elements (and subclasses of it) tries to join the tables of two Element subclasses and then tries to merge the **someValue** columns. As each column has a different type, the engine gives the merged column some type (e.g. Long) and tries to cast all values from the other columns to the decided type.

One DB engine merged the columns and made a Long column. This resulted in the above error. Another DB engine merged the columns and made a Varchar column. This resulted in no error because all my values could be easily transformed to Varchar.